# How to declare an abstract variadic function in PHP before version 5.6?

Tags: php

Does a workaround exist, to declare an abstract variadic function in PHP prior to PHP version 5.6? Beginning from PHP version 5.6, there is an `...` operator which works as follows.

`abstract protected function myVariadicFunction(...$anyNumberOfArgs);`

Implementors now can accept an arbitrary number of arguments. Prior to version 5.6, however, there seems to be only one way, that looks like this.

`abstract protected function myVariadicFunction($arrayOfArgs);`

where `$arrayOfArgs` could be empty or an array filled with any number of arguments.

If there is another, more elegant way, please let me know!

Answer (score 2):

From PHP 5.3 you can use the functions [func_get_args](http://php.net/manual/es/function.func-get-args.php) and [func_num_args](http://php.net/manual/es/function.func-num-args.php) wich returns an array containing the function arguments and a number containing amount of arguments respectively

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't think of anything else:

```php
<?php

abstract class ParentClass
{
    abstract public function variadicMethod($param1, $param2, ...$otherParams);

    abstract public function variadicMethod2();
}

class ChildClass extends ParentClass
{
    public function variadicMethod($param1, $param2, ...$otherParams)
    {
        var_dump(
            $param1,
            $param2,
            $otherParams
        );
    }

    public function variadicMethod2()
    {
        var_dump(
            func_get_args()
        );
    }
}

$child = new ChildClass();
$child->variadicMethod(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);

/* it prints
int(1)
int(2)
array(3) {
  [0] =>
  int(3)
  [1] =>
  int(4)
  [2] =>
  int(5)
}
*/

$child->variadicMethod2(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);

/* it prints
array(5) {
  [0] =>
  int(1)
  [1] =>
  int(2)
  [2] =>
  int(3)
  [3] =>
  int(4)
  [4] =>
  int(5)
}
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you do this in older PHP versions is to use `func_get_args()`.

PHP will silently accept undeclared arguments; you can access them using `func_get_args()` as follows:

```
function myFunc() {
    var_dump(func_get_args());
}

myFunc('foo', 'bar');
```

Output will be show that you have an array containing ('foo', 'bar').

This gives you a pretty good equivalent of a variadic function.

The downsides of this approach (ie the reasons that proper variadic functions were introduced instead) are as follows:

- No ability for IDEs to parse your function's arguments list.
- No ability to use type hinting to specify the type of variable passed in.
- More code and less readable than actual variadics.

But nonetheless, the basic functionality is there.